# How to start R with a package pre-loaded?

Tags: r

I want to start R with a package pre-loaded, using command line. Is there any command line option to do it?

for example something like

`R [SOMEOPTION] [PACKAGENAME]` ?

Also is there any way that I can pass some value into the environment at startup.

```
R [KEY] [VALUE]?
```

Comment: Why not just put all the commands you want executed upon start-up into your .rprofile file?

Comment: Please read: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html

Comment: I need a way for the user to choose whether to load the package or not. I am trying to use that choice  programaticaly